# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined of the Track component

Tags: reactjs

I am following an online course, this is a capstone project. I have to pass information between different components. I have already checked for typos and nothing has caught my eye. I have to use the .map() method to render each track in the tracks property.

I have tried to decompose the code, and do it part by part, however the only part where there seems to be a problem is here,

```
<div class="TrackList">
        {
          this.props.tracks.map(track => {
            return <Track track={track} key={track.id} />
          })
        }
      </div>
```

This is from my TrackList.js code: (Here the code breaks and doesn't recognize the .map() ).

```
import React from 'react';
import './TrackList.css';
import Track from '../Track/Track';

class TrackList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="TrackList">
        {
          this.props.tracks.map(track => {
            return <Track track={track} key={track.id} />
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

export default TrackList;

This code is from my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/SearchBar';
import SearchResults from '../SearchResults/SearchResults';
import Playlist from '../Playlist/Playlist';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchResults: [{name: 'name1', artist: 'artist1', album: 'album1', id: 1}, {name: 'name2', artist: 'artist2', album: 'album2', id: 2}, {name: 'name3', artist: 'artist3', album: 'album3', id: 3}],
      playlistName: 'My Playlist',
      playlistTracks: [{name: 'playlistName1', artist: 'playlistArtist1', album: 'playlistAlbum1', id: 4}]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
        <div className="App">
          <SearchBar />
          <div className="App-playlist">
            <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults} />
            <Playlist />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This code is from my Track.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Track.css';

class Track extends React.Component {
  renderAction() {
    if (this.props.isRemoval) {
      return <button className="Track-action">-</button>
    } else {
      return <button className="Track-action">+</button>
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Track">
        <div className="Track-information">
          <h3>track name</h3>
          <p>track artist | track album</p>
        </div>
        {this.renderAction()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Track;
```

This is from my SearchResults.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchResults.css';
import TrackList from '../TrackList/TrackList';

class SearchResults extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="SearchResults">
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResults} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchResults;
```

All of the previous files are connected with the Track component.

The expected result is the rendering of this component.

Comment: Kindly provide the exact error that you are facing. The error from browser console or the page

Comment: Not sure what could be causing this error, but there's no issue with this code as you've posted it.  Is there any other code that could be causing an issue?

Comment: It says this: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
TrackList.render
src/Components/TrackList/TrackList.js:8
   5 | class TrackList extends React.Component {
   6 |   render() {
   7 |     return (
>  8 |       <div class="TrackList">
   9 |         {
  10 |           this.props.tracks.map(track => {
  11 |             return <Track track={track} key={track.id} />
View compiled
▶ 18 stack frames were collapsed.

Comment: Hello, thank you both very much for your comments. Apparently there was a problem with the course on certain steps and not with the code, so after fixing the order the problem was fixed. Again thank you so much for helping me and taking your time!